# How to center a modal window on a page?

Tags: html, modal-dialog, center

I am trying center a modal window in the browser page. I just want to center it, so that it should be responsive for all the screens.

Comment: try this... http://jsfiddle.net/9t3sn/4/

Comment: Try this great solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53373717/7186739

Answer (score 33):

**With position:absolute** Assuming your modal is 300x300

```
.modal {
   width: 300px;
   height: 300px;
   position: absolute;
   left: 50%;
   top: 50%; 
   margin-left: -150px;
   margin-top: -150px;
}
```

**With display:table** An alternative way for that is to make display table

```
<div class="modal">
    <div class="body">
        <div class="content">
            Content goes here
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<style>
    .modal {display:table;}
    .body {display:table-cell; vertical-align:middle; text-align:center;}
</style>
```

Comment: The problem with `left: 50%;` is that it doesn't take into account the width of the modal itself.

Comment: Then you can play around with top, left, right, bottom like this: .modal { top:200px; left:100px; right:100px; bottom:200px; }

Comment: I don't know why this answer hasn't been accepted yet. `left: 50%; margin-left: -(50% of width);` certainly centers a modal window.

Answer (score 14):

Set bootstrap modal center to any size of screen using css only.

```
.modal {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0!important;
}
.modal:before {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-right: -4px;
}
.modal-dialog {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: left;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

**Browsers & Screens Compatible Solution**

Comment: This is a great solution, because it works for a modal of any width or height.

Answer (score 9):

> Try This in Full Page Preview

```css
   .modal {
       width: 100px;
       height: 100px;
       margin:0 auto;
       display:table;
       position: absolute;
       left: 0;
       right:0;
       top: 50%; 
       border:1px solid;
       -webkit-transform:translateY(-50%);
       -moz-transform:translateY(-50%);
       -ms-transform:translateY(-50%);
       -o-transform:translateY(-50%);
       transform:translateY(-50%);
    }
```

```html
<div class="modal"></div>
```

Comment: I will mention that this solution may cause blurriness on chrome browsers, even latest chromium versions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27385126/chrome-font-appears-blurry

Answer (score 7):

```
.modal
{
position: fixed;
left: 50%;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

If modal container is as following :

```
<div id="containerDiv"> 
   <!--HTML modal -->
 </div>
```

Add css code

```
#containerDiv{
margin : 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: Note: I needed to make sure to not inherit any other margin attributes such as "margin-left" "margin-right" and un-set them.

Answer (score 2):

when showing you modal you should put `display:flex` instead of `block` like most people usualy do. then :

```
<div class="modal" id="modal">
 <div class="modal-content">
  What you want !
 </div>
</div>
```

and CSS :

```
.modal {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;

 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
}
```

remember to put a close button in your `modal-content` because the other element on the screen won't be usable as the `modal` div covers all the screen size.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to show modal on the **center** of the window, follow below steps;

```
.modal {
  text-align: center;
}
.modal-dialog {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: calc(100% - 0rem);
 }
```

Also, by changing **align-items & min-height** you can position modal on place with responsively.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the modal content to be in the center of the modal you could use something like this. In here the top: 50% means the content's start will be 50% from top (note : here 50% is the value respect to the container's height and not it's own) which wont make our content center but when we do translate(-50%,-50%) then the element will traverse 50% upward from its start (note : here -50% is the value respect to it's own height and not the container's)

```
.modal {
  position: fixed;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}
.modal-content {
  background-color: white;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  padding: 2% 7%;
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Tried almost all CSS options, but finally something worked : jQuery

```
setInterval(function()
     {
         if($('#myModal').is(':visible')===true)
         {
             $("body").addClass("modal-open");
             $('#myModal').css({"display":"flex"});
         }
         else
         {
             $("body").removeClass("modal-open");
             $('#myModal').css({"display":"none"});
         }

     },200);
```

This is basic bug from Bootstrap regarding the adding/removal of class **modal-open** to the body tag which is being discussed over the years but no working solution till date.

Answer (score 0):

given class name the whole div, which used modal.

for example:

```
<div class="modal">
in your Content
</div>
```

In your Style:

```
.modal {
display: table;
margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simply calculate top and left to center your modal:

```
position: absolute;
top: calc(50% - halfOfModalHeight);
left: calc(50% - halfOfModalWidth);
```