# Chrome Font appears Blurry

Tags: css, google-chrome

It's doing my eyes in!

looks fine in IE and Firefox

[image]

Chrome(Above)

Running version 39 of chrome,
only appears blurry in a modal box, does not make any difference if I change the font family.

This is the CSS (for label "Start") the browser renders the following

```
box-sizing: border-box;
color: rgb(85, 85, 85);
cursor: default;
display: block;
float: left;
font-family: sans-serif;
font-size: 12px;
font-weight: 600;
height: 24px;
line-height: 17.142858505249px;
margin-bottom: 0px;
margin-top: 0px;
min-height: 1px;
padding-left: 15px;
padding-right: 15px;
padding-top: 7px;
position: relative;
text-align: right;
visibility: visible;
width: 89.65625px;
```

Is it the browser or CSS?

--UPDATE---

Ok looks like its this CSS

```
.md-modal {
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    width: 50%;
    max-width: 630px;
    min-width: 320px;
    height: auto !important;
    z-index: 2000;
    visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%); <--- This line
    -moz-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    -ms-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}
```

However if I take it out my modal no longer centres?

Comment: Are there any CSS transforms on any of the parent elements? It looks like it's being positioned on a decimal of a pixel.

Comment: Can you paste your markup into a JSFiddle or something, to see if it replicates there? The styles alone do not allow me to reproduce this

Comment: You could try something like `-webkit-font-smoothing: none;`

Comment: @BurpmanJunior Hey, not being a CSS expert what am I am looking for?

Comment: Hey updated the main post

Comment: try with `translate3d`

Comment: Do you also have this problem in other browsers?

Comment: @D-W, any luck with my answer?

Comment: Hey, sorry it made no difference, Im now looking to use another modal control instead, appreciate the response tho

Comment: I use matrix normalization after layout : http://stackoverflow.com/a/42256897/1834212

Comment: @D-W change the position: relative; to position: unset;

Answer (score 46):

I fixed this issue by subtracting 0.5px from the value of the Y-axis. So **instead** of doing:

```
transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
```

I did this:

```
transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(calc(-50% - .5px));
```

This solved it for me and I find this a cleaner solution then fiddling around with the percentage or using Javascript.

Comment: It did the trick for me too. Have tried using `perspective()`, with `translateY(50.1%)`, using `scale(1.0, 1.0)` and others solutions.

Comment: most clutch answer I've found in some time :)

Comment: How can you be sure it would be fixed accros all devices ?

Comment: This didn't fix the issue for me (Chrome 75).

Comment: - .4px is sharper :)

Comment: Wow! Probably more hacky than Miguels very good answer but this is so much more reliable to me that it's very worth it until browsers start implementing their own fixes for this

Comment: Stuck on hours and This worked for me. Thanks a lot  :)

Comment: Not sure why this has so many upvotes, this will just fix it if the element height happens to be an odd number of pixels (so `-50%` is not an integer). If it happens to be an even number of pixels, it will do the exact opposite. So the result will vary depending on the size of the browser window.

Answer (score 37):

I experienced the same issue on chrome after applying translate transform to one of my elements. It seems to be a bug on chrome. The only thing that worked for me was this:

```css
#the_element_that_you_applied_translate_to {
  -webkit-filter: blur(0.000001px);
}
```

An Other solution can be turning smooth font rendering on:

```css
#the_element_that_you_applied_translate_to {
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}
```

Comment: Thank you * 100000000. I've been facing this problem for a long time with no good solution.

Comment: excellent solution with blur .. it was only thing that really fix this.
...but from yesterday it seems like this doesn't working anymore. Problem is only with translateY() this is what causes blurry content.
I found that content is blurred only if height of an element is an odd number
_(225px = blured, 224px = sharp as it should be )_.
shame that developers can't fix this for years!!!

At least chrome fully support flex, if your HTML structure allows parent > child(centerend) and you don´t care about IE try this:
https://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/demos/vertical-centering/

Comment: I agreed with @nomak22 explanation.You can check it by changing line-height of the text.

Comment: Does not work at all at the time of this comment. Chrome on Win10. -webkit-font-smoothing has absolutely no effect whatever the value is. And the blur filter just blurs things as it should, while I thought we were trying to remove the blurriness?

Answer (score 34):

[This fiddle tests out a few different solutions](http://jsfiddle.net/00tLy698/1/) from:

- [CSS transition effect makes image blurry / moves image 1px, in Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15464055/css-transition-effect-makes-image-blurry-moves-image-1px-in-chrome)
- [WebKit: Blurry text with css scale + translate3d](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8024061/webkit-blurry-text-with-css-scale-translate3d)
- http://www.useragentman.com/blog/2014/05/04/fixing-typography-inside-of-2-d-css-transforms/

#### Test Output

[image: CSS Output]

#### Fix 0

```
-webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
transform: translateZ(0);
```

#### Fix 3

```
-webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0) !important;
transform: translate3d(0,0,0) !important;
```

Comment: Wow ... is there a reason as to why this fixes it. Or is that a feature by design.

Comment: I'm not clear how this fixes it, your examples are completely overriding the transform he wants. `transform: translateZ(0)` is the last rule applied so the X/Y translations are ignored. This fixes the blurring because the X/Y transforms are the source of the problem. For those trying to center, those x/y transforms *must* remain.

Comment: This is **not a fix** if it's exactly `translate(-50%, -50%)`  (+ no blurry text) what one wants to achieve

Comment: we need a real fix, is this something for google to solve? or is this simple "impossible to fix if someone wants to use transforms" ?

Comment: I think this answer is out of date. I no longer see this issue on the version of Chrome I am running. The issue doesn't present itself in the fiddle above.

Comment: check this transform matrix normalization http://stackoverflow.com/a/42256897/1834212

Comment: In my case I moved a sidebar using ` transform: translateX(-18.75rem);`.
Changing it to use `px` instead: `transform: translateX(-300px)`, no blur anymore.

Comment: If you want to center while applying the fix: `transform: translate3d(-50%, -50%, 0)` does the trick :)

Answer (score 15):

**The only correct way to solve this:**

This problem arises from the fact of using % values to align the divs using css transforms. This results in decimals subpixel values, which your screen cannot render correctly. The solution is to **normalize the resulting transformation matrix.**

Might work better for fixed divs that don´t do transforming animation. But if you do animate you could use a after end callback to this function to correct the final state.

[image]

**So:**
matrix (1,0,0,1,-375,**-451.5**)  *would become* matrix (1,0,0,1,-375,**-451**)

I call this method before the .show() of jquery... Or maybe just once in the application ( depends on your case) , you might need to also call this on the resize event etc..

```
function roundCssTransformMatrix(element){
        var el = document.getElementById(element);
        el.style.transform=""; //resets the redifined matrix to allow recalculation, the original style should be defined in the class not inline.
        var mx = window.getComputedStyle(el, null); //gets the current computed style
        mx = mx.getPropertyValue("-webkit-transform") ||
             mx.getPropertyValue("-moz-transform") ||
             mx.getPropertyValue("-ms-transform") ||
             mx.getPropertyValue("-o-transform") ||
             mx.getPropertyValue("transform") || false;
        var values = mx.replace(/ |\(|\)|matrix/g,"").split(",");
        for(var v in values) { values[v]=v>4?Math.ceil(values[v]):values[v]; }

        $("#"+element).css({transform:"matrix("+values.join()+")"});

}
```

and call it

```
roundCssTransformMatrix("MyElementDivId");
$("#MyElementDivId").show();
```

Beautiful isn't it?

If you need to update on resize you could do it with:

```
$( window ).resize(function() {
  roundCssTransformMatrix("MyElementDivId");  
});
```

> For this to work, all the parent must "be aligned / normalized"
>   because if you by instance have the body with x=10.1px left, and the
>   child is 10px .. the issue wont disapear because of the parent having residual decimals on their matrix
>   So you must apply this function to the each element that is a parent and
>   uses transform.

You can see this live script here: https://jsbin.com/fobana/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: I was hoping for a css only solution, but this will do. I can't use any of the other suggestions on here as I'm using this css for multiple elements on the page. Some but not all elements have a round number when giving a -50% offset. So setting it to calc(-50% - .5px) would fix some elements, but break others.

Answer (score 10):

Thanks for the CSS example. It seems `translateX(50%)` and `translateY(50%)` are calculating a pixel value with a decimal place (eg, 0.5px) which causes subpixel rendering.

There are many fixes for this but if you want to retain the quality of the text, your best solution right now is to use `-webkit-font-smoothing: subpixel-antialiased;` on `.md-modal` to force the render state for webkit browsers like Chrome and Safari.

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply, I added that line, but no affect im afraid

Comment: @D-W have you found a solution yet? Do you have a Codepen or jsFiddle we can look at?

Comment: I Math.round() 'ed the translateX(x) value for my code and the rendering is now smooth. Thanks.

Comment: @mak - can you provide some more detail on exactly how you implemented your solution using Math.round() ?

Comment: I upvote this answer not because the solution worked for me, but because the first paragraph make me clear about what the cause of this issue. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

I ended up fixing this by removing these lines:

```
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
-moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
backface-visibility: hidden;
```

Answer (score 5):

It took me a while to find a solution that I wouldn't bother using, so I'll post it here.

The problem for me was that the child `div` had `width` and `height` properties with a combination that caused the problem.

As I changed the `height` for another value, it just worked!

This probably has to do with the other answers, but I didn't want to use any JS or change the transform property to fix it.

Here is a live example: [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/Airton/jr10qfau/2/)

Comment: I am confused as to how this works.. but thanks for sharing. I will try this.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to center something, better use flexbox. It will help you position without having blurred text.

Add this to **parent div** of that element you want to center:

```
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Seems Chrome 78 still has this bug https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=521364.

Building upon previous answers, I found the CSS below gave me the sharpest display on a translated modal:

```
transform: translate(calc(-50% - .4px), calc(-50% - .4px));
```

**EDIT:**
For IE11 compatibility:

```
transform: translateX(-50%) translateX(-0.4px) translateY(-50%) translateY(-0.4px);
```

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old issue but since i stumbled across it in 2022 I thought I just tell someone who needs this how I solved it in my situation:

I had a modal with a textarea in it and in Chrome it was displayed blurry, but only when the textarea was overflowing.
My modal - NOT the textarea itself - had `overflow: hidden;` so I just removed that.

[image][image]

Comment: what if you need the overflow though?

Answer (score 1):

For modal boxes, this css will help:

```
-webkit-transform: translate3d(-50%, -51%, 0);
-moz-transform: translate3d(-50%, -51%, 0);
transform: translate3d(-50%, -51%, 0);
```

Instead of placing Y axis at 50%, make it 51%. This helps in my cse.
If you have a different positioning, play around, but usually 1% up/down fixes blurry content.

Answer (score 1):

**TLDR**

I faced this problem a few days ago. I almost went crazy trying to sharpen the fonts in Chrome. I have read all posts in this thread and in all other posts regarding sharpening fonts in Chrome. Even the message "The only correct way to solve this" did not help in my case. What helped?

It is worth mentioning that the problem occurred in the following div:

```
position: sticky;
left: 16%;
```

And the 'sticky' attribute turned out to be the biggest problem. For sticky elements, we set the position as for 'absolute' elements - using attributes the 'left', 'top' etc. And here is the problem: with not integer values ​​of the 'left' the font is rendered dramatically blurry, with integers it is much better.

What is the solution?

```
position: sticky;    
left: 0;
margin-left: 16%;
```

And that's all. Chrome will handle the percentage 'margin' and the fonts will look sharp.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a CSS transition to the parent element of the parent element of my blurry element (which was using transformX which was causing blurriness) actually cancelled out the offending blurriness.

Answer (score 0):

The similar issue happened for me.

I tried with all the suggested methods none worked fine.  However,finally I resolved it.
As there is an issue with google chrome having `font-weight:600` or more.
Try changing the font-family to `font-family:"Webly Sleek SemiBold","Helvetica";`

The font-weight property will work fine for it.

[image: Blur_Font]

[image: Without_Blur]

Answer (score 0):

Another cause may be that you are not providing the needed font weights that you are utilizing.

For example, if you want to use both Lato or Roboto you want to include more than just the standard weight. This example applies if you are using Google Font API:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,900|Roboto:500,700">
```

Note: Lato is available in 100, 300, 400, 700, and 900 font-weight, but I had to specify 900 for my 700 text to become crisp...not sure why.

Answer (score 0):

For now, I found only one good solution:

```
transform: translate(-50%, -50.1%)
```

0.1% - in general user can't see this

Hope chrome will fix it - the bug exists since 2014))))

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want implementing any special js or custom solution and the only what you want to achieve is center your div, and the width and height does not have fixed size, you can simply use this:

```
position: absolute;
left: 0;
right: 0;
top: 0;
bottom: 0;
margin: auto;
```

If one of sizes is fixed, you can try this approach:

```
position: absolute;
left: 50%;
translate: transformX(-50%);
top: 0;
bottom: 0;
margin: auto;
```

It fixes the problem with blurred font in chrome.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this issue by putting:

```css
    transform: inherit;
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way I've found to resolve this issue which appears to only be an issue in Chrome and only on specific screen sizes, is to replace all *transform:translate(-50%,50%)* definitions with alternate solutions. Using any other solution may solve it on your screen, but not on another.

Transform definitions are usually used to center elements. Rather than using a transform definition, find another way to center your element, problem will be solved. In our case, we had a fixed div we wanted centered, with a max-width of 1800px and bottom set to 0px;

```
#cntr{position:fixed;left:50%;bottom:0;width:100%;max-width:1800px;transform:translateX(-50%);-ms-transform:translateX(-50%);-webkit-transform:translateX(-50%);-moz-transform:translateX(-50%);-o-transform:translateX(-50%);text-align:center;}
```

Lot of definitions in there to cover all browsers. Changed to this to resolve it :

```
#cntr{position:fixed;left:0;right:0;margin:auto;bottom:0;width:100%;max-width:1800px;text-align:center;}
```

A lot less code, cleaner, faster, and worked 100%, without needing to edit any HTML.

Definitions that now center the fixed pos div are: left:0;right:0;margin:auto;

No translate required, no decimal point placed divs.

Answer (score 0):

For those still trying to find a solution to this, setting background fixed it for me for some reason.

```
background: #fff;
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that applying the `translate3d(0, 0, 0)` fix as JSuar suggested worked in Chrome but not Safari.

The one thing that did work across browsers was to give the element I was centring (using `transform: translate(50%, -50%)`) an even pixel width — changing the width from 425px to 426px made the text sharp again.

Answer (score 0):

The issue often happens with `position: fixed;` and `transform: translate(...)` when the width and height of the element are not a round even number.

One of the solutions is to round up the numbers programmatically. Example:

```
function roundToEven(x) {
  const rounded = Math.round(x)
  return rounded % 2 ? rounded + 1 : rounded
}
const element = document.getElementById('element-id')
const rect = element.getBoundingClientRect()
element.style.width = roundToEven(rect.width) + 'px'
element.style.height = roundToEven(rect.height) + 'px'
```

Answer (score 0):

You should choose your font with corresponding **font weight** which you want if you want thin, regular and bold text. You should choose font with weight 100 | 400 | 700 example: like below

Font weight is not only number. File should be available in server or directory.
Each font weight is separate file.

If you force to change regular font into bold without resource, it showing with blurry. I hope you get it.

> @import
> url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@100;400;700&display=swap');

Comment: Thanks, this was exactly my problem!

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone is having this issue using the Roboto font from Google. My text was looking sort of blurry. I noticed that I wasn't importing the correct font-weight from Google. I needed 700 but wasn't including it.

```
https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@300;400;500&display=swap
```

vs

```
https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@300;400;500;700&display=swap
```

Answer (score -1):

I had this issue with my site as well, using a similar setup.
The issue appears because of a `0.5px` difference.
An easy fix is to change the top property from `50%` to `calc(50% - .5px)`