# The content of some div becomes blurry when running an ajax function on some browsers

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I am currently working on a web application project as part of my developer training. Its principle is quite simple, it is a search engine dedicated to listing the results of SQL queries on a database belonging to a customer, and previously migrated. I have a particular problem, indeed, on some browsers (those based on chrome), when displaying the results (they are in a table) the content of some divs tags becomes blurry and a little unreadable. This is probably a common problem, however I have not found anything clear about this bug. The blurred area is at the top of the page.

Here is the function called on search:

```
function rechercher()
{
    var name = document.getElementById('rech').value;
    var checked = 0;
    var selectedMarque = $('#marque :selected').text();
    var selectedType = $('#type :selected').text();
    var selectedCat = $('#cat :selected').text();
    var selectedCompagnie = $('#compagnie :selected').text();

    if ($('#inputFerro').is(":checked"))
    {
        var checked = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        var checked = 0;
    }

    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "./fonction/some.php",
    data: {name: name, checked:checked, selectedMarque: selectedMarque, selectedType:selectedType, selectedCat: selectedCat, selectedCompagnie: selectedCompagnie},
    success: function(msg){
        if(checked == 0)
        {
            $('#resultat').empty();
            if(msg.length <= 2)
            {
                $('#resultat').empty();
                $('#resultat').append("Aucun résultat");
                $('#resultat').append('<table id="tblRes"></table>');
            }
            else
            {
                $('#resultat').append('<table id="tblRes"></table>');
                $('#tblRes').append("<tr><th>Compagnie</th><th>Type</th><th>Numéro</th><th>Marque</th><th>Essieux</th><th>Catégorie</th><th>Échelle</th></tr>");
                $('#tblRes').append(msg);
            }

        }
        else
        {
            $('#tblRes').empty();
            $('#tblRes').append("<tr><th>Type</th><th>Numero article</th><th>Marque</th><th>Catégorie</th><th>Echelle</th></tr>");
            $('#tblRes').append(msg);
        }

    }
    });
}
```

And the result div where result are stocked in :

```
<div id="resultat">
    <table id="tblRes">

    </table>
</div>
```

I share with you below screenshots of the situation, hoping that the blurred effect will be visible.

Here is the rendering under chrome (buggy version):
[chrome version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FTnBr.png)

Here is the rendering under firefox:
[mozilla version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jGRMh.png)

Web application link: [www.ferrovipathe.ch](https://ferrovipathe.ch)

This project is under development and is therefore not complete. No need to comment on the rest of the operation :D I apologize in advance if I did not ask my question in accordance with all the standards required by SO. This is my very first post! :)

Comment: Maybe you should include a (minimal self-content) piece of code that shows what you've already did?

Comment: Just looks like normal Chrome anti-aliasing to me, increase the contrast, switch the font or make it a little bigger (Arial isn't idea at that size).

Comment: "_when displaying the results (they are in a table) the content of some divs tags becomes blurry_" So the content is crisp when **not** displaying the results?

Comment: @CD001 Interesting, so it's only my chrome install ?

Comment: @kerbholz No, when you launch a search and display result, it become blurry on my screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tested it on your site by modifying the CSS and it seemed to work for me :/
Nomatter, I found the real problem, you've a `margin-top: 0px` on your CSS and if you remove it, it seems to show without blur, hope this answer will help you resolve this annoying bug...

Here are some proofs :

Your page with the `margin-top: 0px`

[image: Your css]
[image: All blury]

Your page without the line

[image: Without CSS]
[image: Not blurry]

Answer (score 0):

I think I've found something for you, here's the [source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35955074/12130402)

```
    #yourDiv {
      -webkit-filter: blur(0.000001px);
    }
```

```
    #yourDiv {
      -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    }
```

Hope it'll help you ;)