# How can I fix the image wiggle on transform? Embedly on the page fixes it?

Tags: css, css-transforms, embedly

If the size of the image is 200.51px there is no wiggle, but if it is 200.49px there is a wiggle due to the transformation matrix rounding. This is detailed in this article [Chrome Font appears Blurry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27385126/chrome-font-appears-blurry/42256897#42256897)

An interesting thing though, is if I have an Embedly component on the page, the issue goes away.  What is Embedly adding to the global css?

Before I try to implement something like the link demonstrates to fix my wiggle problem when doing `transform: scale(1.1);`, I would like to know if there is a more straightforward fix that can be added to my css, as it seems that Embedly is doing that.

Thank you for any insight in advance.

Comment: Seems that I may be wrong about being able to fix the problem through transformation matrix rounding, as when I log it out I get (1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0).  Not sure what approach I can take to fix this problem now.  Would love to be able to manually round the value down through css, but I don't know if this is possible.